# My application has stopped unexpectedly on emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-manifest

Im new to android development ,im just following tutorials so while running project as android application on emulator it is showing "your application has stopped unfortunately". I have seen so many answers in stackoverflow but didn't get solution. I went to logcat also .
what I have done
just simply run my hello world in emulator but it was stopped.

1) this is my xml activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.examp.calc.MainActivity" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="40sp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

2) Java source code : activity file

```
package com.examp.calc;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}}
```

3)Mainfest file

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.examp.calc"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
`
```

4)logcat error report:

> 03-10 06:56:55.347: D/AndroidRuntime(1761): Shutting down VM
>       03-10 06:56:55.347: W/dalvikvm(1761): threadid=1: thread exiting with ncaught exception (group=0xb0d77b20)
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761): Process: com.examp.calc, PID: 1761
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.examp.calc/com.exam.calc.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.exam.calc.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.examp.calc-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.examp.calc-1, /system/lib]]
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.exam.calc.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.examp.calc-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.examp.calc-1, /system/lib]]
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
>   03-10 06:56:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     ... 11 more

5) after debugging :
[source not found in debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzWnb.png)
thank you advance

Comment: thanku but still I'm getting same error 
ur calc has stopped unexpectedly

Comment: Try changing your **extends ActionBarActivity** by **extends Activity**

Comment: thanku now its worked but I kept both setContentview and tools:context

Answer (score 1):

You must not define;

```
tools:context="com.examp.calc.MainActivity"
```

and

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

at the same time. Just remove one of them and it will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `extends ActionBarActivity` by `extends Activity`.

---

The compiler search for the package **com.exam.calc** but your package name is **com.examp.calc**.

In your `Manifest`, replace :

```
android:name="com.exam.calc.MainActivity"
```

By :

```
android:name="com.examp.calc.MainActivity"
```

---

If it's not working, you can try this...

Try deleting this line in your xml layout :

```
tools:context="com.examp.calc.MainActivity"
```

You should have :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:textSize="40sp" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Or if you prefer, you can delete the `setContentView` line of your `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

In Mainfest file : change this line

> android:name="com.examp.calc.MainActivity"